# Foreign key in one table have high read performance or another table with two primary key?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, database-design, relational-database

I want to know witch one is better for high read performance.
Foreign key in one table have high read performance or another table with composite key?

> In Figure1 "idInvoice" is nullable some Sanads come without Factor

#### Q1- For example I want to list all Notes Invoice or Find is there any Invoice for special Note.

#### Q2- Which one is better if "idInvoice" can not be null.

> Figure1

Table Invoice:

```
idInvoice //Primary key
invoiceNumber
value
costumerId
```

Table Note:

```
idNote //Primary key
type
liable
credit
idInvoice // Foreign key (Nullable)
```

OR

> Figure 2

Table Invoice:

```
idInvoice //Primary key
invoiceNumber
value
costumerId
```

Table Note:

```
idNote //Primary key
type
liable
credit
```

Table InvoiceNote:

```
idNote //composite key - Foreign key
idInvoice //composite key - Foreign key
```

Comment: @Solarflare  You maen if there is no null FK better all data store in one table and if there is many null FK better seperate two table. Is it correct?

Comment: You cannot have 2 primary keys. You can use a composite primary key `FactorSanad(idDana, idFactor)`, but that would be a different situation: it would describe that every Sanad can have several Factors and vice versa. If that is the case, use 2, otherwise 1 (though 2 is possible too, just taste). Your data model should define your tables, not microoptimization. Which one is faster depends on your data and exact query. A rule of thumb: If you have about 10% Sanads with a Factor, 2 can make sense. But it really depends on your exakt queries and data. In general, 1 should be faster (less joins)

Comment: @Solarflare  I want to design my model therefore I want to select best way to design my model. My model must support 10^6 Sanads or more 90% have Factor and My another Model must support 10^6 Sanads with 40% of Factor which one is better for each Model?

Comment: @Solarflare uhu must query is summation of Sanad fileds Sanad is like accountancy table

Comment: I meant: That actually comes down to personal taste. Both options are correct. Some prefer not to use figure 2 at all, Some would say you should use figure 2 every time. So there is no correct answer for that. 10% is a "reasonable" compromise (but even that number is a matter of opinion). StackOverflow is not about opinions, so I won't tell you which one you have to use, as it actually depends on your data, your whole model/reality and your (other) queries. Though from your (limited) information you gave I would use 1 (easier, less joins). But as I said, the next guy could say "take 2".

Comment: @Solarflare Yes. I understand you. Thank you to explain. appreciated and thanks

Comment: Although I don't see the "accountancy" in your table strucure (items should always belong to an account), account tables will always be modeled by figure 1; well, actually, the values will usually even be copied to the item tables (to make sure that changes in other tables (classic mistake: VAT) will not change e.g. an older invoice). That's was just as a remark. You didn't specify enough to make that assumption, but "account" made alarm bells ring in my ears, so make sure you follow all regulations in your country. Anyway, good luck.

Comment: @Solarflare Question updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer revolves around "many:many" versus "1:many".

Is this a many:many relationship?  If so then follow the tips [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table).  Notice that it does have a composite PK, plus an index for mapping in the opposite direction.

If this is a 1:many relationship, perhaps with "many" sometimes being "0", then the right technique is to have an `id` in one of the tables for linking to the other table (with our without an actual FK).  And `NULL` is probably the right value to represent "none".